# How to change the font in the running headers in the article class

Tags: fancyhdr

How do I change (only!) the font in the running headers in article class. I know the answer: use fancyhdr. However, the defaults in fancyhdr are very different from the article class, which means I have to design a pagestyle in fancyhdr, which means I have to read the fancyhdr manual, which is 76 pages long. All to change the fonts in the running headers. Surely there's an easier way.

Two good answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `fancyhdr` (version 4 or later):

You are talking about running headers, so I assume you use `\pagestyle{headings}`. Fancyhdr has an option to emulate this pagestyle, but with a rule under the headers, which you can easily eliminate. To change the font, the font definition can be put in `\fancyhfinit`. In the example I choose boldface sans serif as the font.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Eliminate the rule under the headers.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhfinit{\bfseries\sffamily}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[2-11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the default plain page style used by `article` is not changed by `fancyhdr` so they should not be "very different"  but if you don't want that, just copy the definitions from latex.ltx  or article.cls and add the font commands, eg the default plain page stype is

```
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage
     \hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

so

```
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\bfseries\color{red}\hfil\thepage
     \hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

will give you bold red page numbers in the default `plain` page style.